# How do you say "a person is convinced that"

Tags: grammaire

The context is as follows:

> Jerome is convinced that all children are born with an innate musical desire.

How do you say this sentence, would it be reflexive, and also would it be direct or passive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "Jérôme est convaincu que" (tous les enfants sont nés avec un désir
>   inné pour la musique).

or

> "Jérôme est persuadé que"